# error missing return statement in method

Tags: java, android, database

I want to get data based on a `fragment` of the name , but why the error with a description of the missing `return` statement ?

```
public Cursor getName (String nama){
    Cursor c = db.query(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL, new String[]{
            Konstanta.ID_ARTIS,
            Konstanta.NAMA_ARTIS,
            Konstanta.GENDER_ARTIS_PRIA,
            Konstanta.GENDER_ARTIS_WANITA,
            Konstanta.TGLAHIR}, Konstanta.NAMA_ARTIS + "LIKE '%" + nama + "%'",
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: your return statement is inside your if condition and thats why the function not going to return a statement, thats the reason behind error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method returns a result only if `c` is not null. It must return a result in all scenarios, i.e. even if `c` is null.

You can change

```
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
```

to

```
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, n everyone who has helped answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Every method which has a return value must return the described bean. You need to return `null` or throw a custom exception if `c` is not null.

```
public Cursor getName (String nama){
        Cursor c = db.query(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL, new String[]{
                Konstanta.ID_ARTIS,
                Konstanta.NAMA_ARTIS,
                Konstanta.GENDER_ARTIS_PRIA,
                Konstanta.GENDER_ARTIS_WANITA,
                Konstanta.TGLAHIR}, Konstanta.NAMA_ARTIS + "LIKE '%" + nama + "%'",
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            return c;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("c is null");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add below line -

```
return null;
```

in your code block -

```
public Cursor getName (String nama){
    Cursor c = db.query(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL, new String[]{
            Konstanta.ID_ARTIS,
            Konstanta.NAMA_ARTIS,
            Konstanta.GENDER_ARTIS_PRIA,
            Konstanta.GENDER_ARTIS_WANITA,
            Konstanta.TGLAHIR}, Konstanta.NAMA_ARTIS + "LIKE '%" + nama + "%'",
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }

return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method must `return` Cursor type value but you are returning value only in a `if` loop

do this way :

```
 public Cursor getName (String nama){
 Cursor c =null;
 c = db.query(Konstanta.NAMA_TABEL, new String[]{
            Konstanta.ID_ARTIS,
            Konstanta.NAMA_ARTIS,
            Konstanta.GENDER_ARTIS_PRIA,
            Konstanta.GENDER_ARTIS_WANITA,
            Konstanta.TGLAHIR}, Konstanta.NAMA_ARTIS + "LIKE '%" + nama + "%'",
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }
   return c;
   }
```